# Studying the existence of the partial derivatives of $f(x,y) = |x|$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to find out if the partial derivatives of the following function exist at $(0,0)$.

$$f(x,y)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
|x| \quad \text{ if }y = x^2 \\ 
0  \quad \text{ if }y \neq x^2
\end{array}
\right.$$

**My attempt:**

The x-derivative at zero is:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=  \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}$$

So it will exist if the side derivatives exist and are equal.

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{|t|}{t} = \frac{-t}{t}=-1$$

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{|t|}{t} = \frac{t}{t}=1$$

So the x-derivative doesn't exist. However my book says both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ exist and are equal to zero. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your function is given by two different rules deending on the values of $x$ and $y$.  You seem to have assumed that $f(t,0)$ is **always** equal to $|t|$, it's not.  In fact for $f(t,0)$ we have

- if $0=t^2$ then $f(t.0)=|t|=0$;
- if $0\ne t^2$ then $f(t,0)=0$;

in other words, $f(t,0)$ is always $0$.  So
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)
  =\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}
  =\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{t}=0\ .$$
Try the other for yourself.